# Errors when trying to update rects using d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a button that redraws my stacked bar chart using information from a new csv file that is identical to the csv file apart from the values.

The chart itself is redrawing but the rectangles aren't resizing and I am getting the following error:

```
selection.selectAll(...).data is not a function
```

I have run tests and the data does exist. I am new to d3 and it's all a bit confusing at the moment.

This is the block of code that creates the error:

```
        var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

        //add x and y axis      
        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);

   var selection = svg.selectAll(".series")
        .duration(750)          
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.quarter) + "," + y2(d.quarter) +")"; });

        //error happens after this part
        selection.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function (d) { return d.mapping; })
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y1); })
          .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
          .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.name); })
          .style("stroke", "grey")
          .on("mouseover", function (d) { showPopover.call(this, d); })
          .on("mouseout",  function (d) { removePopovers(); })
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `selection` variable is actually a transition and not a selection, and that doesn't have a `.data()` function. You need something like

```
 var svg = d3.select("body");

    //add x and y axis      
    svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(xAxis);
// etc

var selection = svg.selectAll(".series");

selection.duration(750)          
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.quarter) + "," + y2(d.quarter) +")"; });

    selection.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function (d) { return d.mapping; })
    .enter().append("rect")
   // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just updated the code above as I noticed that the transition is added to body. Does your fix still apply?

Comment: The main thing is that you shouldn't save a transition as a selection. I'll update the answer.